# Install Emotiv Xavier Control Panel on Raspberry Pi3 / Raspbian Stretch

Tags: raspbian, linux, ubuntu

I want to install [Emotive Xavier Control Panel](https://www.emotiv.com/) on a Raspberry Pi3, running Raspbian Sretch.

A version exists for Ubuntu Linux.  Can I install this on my Pi?

Comment: No. I'm asking how to install application 'x' -which has a version for linux ubuntu- on Rasbian strech.

Comment: My application program is Emotiv Xavier control panel.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably struggle. I couldn't easily get hold of the program to check, but by "Linux Ubuntu" it very likely means "...on an Intel/AMD processor", and it's likely that it includes binaries which will have been compiled for those processors.

If it were open-source, you could (probably) compile it yourself, but it appears it's not.